# 2nd HDD mounted, but as read only ntfs

Tags: mount, hard-drive, nautilus, automount

first hard drive has ubuntu partition and windows partition.  But mainly I'm using ubuntu.

2nd drive is nearly blank, and has just the single partition with free space.

[image: drive is blank]

I was trying to move some files to the 2nd drive, but I get an error that it is "read only"

[image: description here]

How do I make the 2nd drive writable within ubuntu?   I never had these problems in windows or Mac when I have used those laptops.  You pop in a drive and it is available to all the user's programs immediately for read/write.  At worst, you might have to format it if it is unformatted,  or restart computer.

ps  tried to run sudo nautilus as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1118023/932570)

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:91887): WARNING **: 11:35:42.565: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:91887): WARNING **: 11:35:42.565: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 11:35:43.090: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

and this nautilus process is still running after a good 20 min!  I had to use <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> to stop it.

Also `ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`

```
Mounting volume... Error opening read-only '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening read-only '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Permission denied
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': Read-only file system
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

and then `chkdsk /dev/sdb1`
`chkdsk: command not found`

So there you have it folks.

Comment: `Permission denied` suggests that perhaps you omitted `sudo`

Comment: You run `chkdsk` while booted into Windows. It's a Windows utility, and the appropriate best tool for repairing an NTFS filesystem.

Comment: `chkdsk` is an old DOS (and thus windows) command; it's not a POSIX, Unix or Linux command so *command not found* is expected.   If a file-system *flips* RO it's commonly because of corruption problems being detected; and flipping to RO prevents data loss...  Did you verify the reason in your logs? and then check your disk health for issues? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) though there are many causes for it (logs are where to look first)

Comment: Most common issue is Windows has fast startup or hibernation on. Turn it off: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

NTFS is a proprietary Microsoft file system. The source code is not published, so we cannot expect that some Linux tool can really find all possible errors and fix them.

This means that you should **run Windows and use its tools to repair NTFS** (and the same applies to FAT32 and exFAT). There is `chkdsk` and there are graphical interface tools in Windows for this purpose.